# Ranking SOLR results by query

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR DIH-conig.xml (dataimporter) with multiple queries, querying different tables (or views) in Oracle 11.

I simply want SOLR to return results from one specific query first before returning the results from the other queries.

How should I configure this in DIH-config.xml?

Thanks.

regards,
Erik

Comment: did you tried by having multiple entities in the data-config.xml?

Comment: yes. I have multiple entities per table or view..

Answer (score 1):

You can't configure that in `data-config.xml` in any way - what Solr returns is based on what's in the index. The Data Import Handler only imports data into Solr, the SQL queries aren't used for anything outside of getting data into Solr.

However you can work around this through having a special field with static values returned from each query, effectively identifying which query the document was imported from.

In your SQL query, add an aliased field name as the priority of the document:

```
SELECT ..., 1000 AS priority FROM ...
```

In the second query, do the same, but with a higher priority value:

```
SELECT ..., 2000 AS priority FROM ...
```

This require defining a long / integer field named `priority` first if you're not running in schemaless mode.

When querying Solr, use this value as the first sort criteria (`sort=priority, score`). This will give all documents from the first query first, internally sorted by score, then from the last query, also internally sorted by score.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh,  thanks for your quick response. I will look into it. But am I right you're saying the standard way is to determine priority in the frontend URL's instead of in the dataimporter?

Comment: It'll be a lot more flexible at least - instead of assigning priority, assign a source identifier and use that for boosting. It'll allow you to weigh the different source differently instead of just sorting by them. My main point is Solr itself has no relationship to your queries - they're just one of many ways to get data into Solr. So if you want to do something different based on which query the document originated from, you have to attach that information to the documents when they're being imported.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Just to be clear, I want results from one table to have higher priority than the others. So I need to distinguish between tables (or views) and between fields. If you have an example URL it would be great. But many thanks so far. regards, Erik

Comment: As I gave in my answer, you'll have to append that information in your SQL queries first when importing, then use the `sort` parameter to tell Solr you want one set of documents ordered before the other set. The URL otherwise will depend on your Solr query.